# SFMC error: 'There is no user mapping for this Salesforce account in Marketing Cloud'

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am following the Marketing Cloud Connect Trailhead here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/finish-mc-connect-configuration

I cannot ever seem to get to this part successfully:

- Log in to Marketing Cloud.
- Hover over your username and select Setup.
- Click Apps and select Salesforce Integration.
- Make sure Scope by User is deselected.
- Click Connect Account.

I am a Sys Admin in SFMC and when I navigate to Setup | Apps | Salesforce Integration, I see:

'Connected App authentication is now available for this account. Click 'Edit' to upgrade.'

The interwebs advised me I can go to Email Studio | Admin and then select 'Edit' and upgrade but I don't see that option at all. In Email Studio | Admin, I see:

[image]

There isn't an 'Edit' button available there but when I go to 'Account Settings' and select 'Edit', there is no 'Connect Account' option.

I have double checked I am a SFMC admin and I have these permissions:

- Administrator
- Marketing Cloud Administrator

I have double checked that my user in SFMC is also an API user.

In Sales cloud, under Marketing Cloud tab, I keep getting the '*There is no user mapping for this Salesforce account in Marketing Cloud*' error message for the Salesforce System User. I was able to connect to the MC API User though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says "current tracking user credentials are inherited from parent".

So, please go to your parent business unit and do the same step. You can able to view the Edit button.

If you want to see the edit button in child business to connect other Salesforce orgs. Then you can raise a ticket to Salesforce to enable 'Multi Org business unit'.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Naveen - thanks so much - that's a great suggestion!

Comment: You are welcome @Andy !